# Creating a simple button inside of a widget

Tags: widgets, css, html, links, buttons

So I'm wanting to add a couple of buttons in a footer text widget. It should be a really easy task by just creating a class inside of a link, and then styling it with CSS, like this:

`<a href="/newsletter" class="news-button">Newsletter</a>`

`a.news-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
}`

Normally, this would work fine, like in this JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b9mc74p1/

However in my WordPress widget, `.et_pb_widget a` is overriding everything else. And if I tried to just apply CSS to `.et_pb_widget a`, it's going to add it to all my widget links, which I do not want.

I even tried adding `!important` (I know, that's bad practice) but it still didn't work. I'd rather avoid a plugin for something this simple. Any ideas?

Link: http://mygirlfriends.kitemedia.com/ (footer, bottom right widget)

Comment: If the widget doesn't have any hooks/filters then you might be able to do it by modifying the whole output instead. See-> https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/06/filter-output-wordpress-widget/

If you have access to change your theme, I would consider using wp_nav_menu instead, and create a footer menu under Appearances -> Menus.

Comment: Why would the `!important` have not worked? If that didn't work, there's probably some problem that will be hard to overcome. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Sure, it's http://mygirlfriends.kitemedia.com/. In the footer, bottom right widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not tie them all together?

```
.et_pb_widget a.news-button {
    color: green;  //example color.
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, but it's giving me the same issue.

Comment: just tried it with debugger and it worked fine...did you put that in the style.css?

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time...I had an extra bracket in my stylesheet. You're right, it did work. I'll close this thread. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries.  It happens.  Can you mark it as answered?